# Change size of StringProperty Text Input

Tags: python, properties, panel

Is there a way to increase the vertical height of a [StringProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/bpy.types.StringProperty.html)? My goal is to have a multi line text entry field.

[image: Panel Example]

I have applied a [scale_y](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.scale_y) which works on operator buttons but doesn't seem to work on a StringProperty

```
    sub = col.row()
    sub.scale_y = 3.0
    sub.operator("render.render")
    sub.prop(scene.video_info,"video_description")
```

#### Edit for clarification

My objective is to have a text entry field that can accept an arbitrary amount of user input including multiple lines. I would want it to look something like this:

[image: example of desired outcome]

I know that the `Enter` key causes the input to be finished. I had made the assumption that could be disabled. If not then this question may be futile in the first place.

The "why" is that I have created an add-on to allow uploading rendered videos to Youtube from within Blender. This would be the description field for a video.
[image: example of current plugin]

Comment: AFAIK it isn't possible.  Even the text on the big button above isn't  bigger, same for labels.

Comment: Use `UILayout.split()` to make columns using a percentage of the available width. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51263/935)

Comment: I don't see your point how `split()` helps to fit the property vertically @sambler. Out of curiosity: Can you elaborate on that please? AFAIK multi line is also not possible so there is no chance to achieve that.

Comment: Given your new edit, as a workaround, maybe a link to text block for description could be way to go for long descriptions.

Comment: Looking at that question, I would have to agree that it does answer mine.

Comment: @batFINGER That is what I was starting to think I would end up doing. It looks like the code for that patch is nearly complete and I don't know why it wasn't approved. I may try to build blender with it and see what is left to do.

Comment: One could argue that multi line text boxes would only add clutter to UI, does it wrap, scroll, crop on panel resize,  and not add any functionality that the text editor already gives.